# Property is already in use in the system with another data type

Tags: content-hub

We created a `taxonomy` field in the `Content Hub schema`, but later we came to know that we need to change its field type to `integer`. So we deleted the existing field and click on Apply changes. Then when trying to create a field again with an `integer` type then it showed an error saying - `Property 'AttributesGeneralPTouch.MemoryLocations' is already in use in the system with another data type`.

[image]

```
Sitecore.NET 10.1.2 (rev. 006578)
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You have made a taxonomy association with any of the items, and you are getting this error. Remove existing taxonomy item relations and try again.

Comment: I did it already but that didn't help.

Comment: You have to remove the taxonomy relation from the schema first and then delete the taxonomy item.

Comment: Go to Taxonomy > Search for your taxonomy > Click on Show definition > Delete all the items which are related to your taxonomy item and click on 'Apply CHanges' > Now try to delete your own taxonomy item.

Comment: I did it already this as well but no success, also tried to clear the cache as well.